# How to clear BufferedReader in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

To read data from my serial port I am using an inputStream and using `BufferedReader` for the inputStream. After each read I want to clear the `BufferedReader`. Under the class `BufferedReader` there is no clear method. I tried to use `reset()` but it didn't work. Any geeks here to suggest anything on this problem?

Comment: What do you mean clear the BufferReader?  After you write, you can flush the buffer - but I'm not aware of any need to clear the buffer after reading.

Comment: you mean to say u want to make null the buffered objects?

Comment: DataInputStream inStream;
BufferedReader bufRd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
while((str = bufRd.readLine()) != null){
System.out.println(str);
}

In the above code , everytime do readLine() I get the previously read contents also. Like fist time I read "abc" and then second time i get "abcdef". But i need only "def".

Comment: the posted code in above comment works for me , doesnot duplicate. Here is mine InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\LOGFILE.txt");
    BufferedReader bufRd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
    while ((str = bufRd.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(str);
    }

Answer (score 9):

Just for readability - this is the code you posted in the comment (with the additional definition of str)

```
DataInputStream inStream = null;
String str = null; 
BufferedReader bufRd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream)); 
while((str = bufRd.readLine()) != null){ 
  System.out.println(str); 
}
```

Yes, it should work. There is no need to 'clear' or 'reset' a Stream or a Streamreader. Everything you read from the reader is 'taken from it', you will not see it again with the next read.

So if you really see items reappear on the Reader (and you haven't 'customized' the reader itself), then it is most likely, that your data source is sending the same data again and again. Check in that area.

Answer (score 3):

Try to make a new instance of buffer

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); //create
String read = br.readLine(); //read line
br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

I'm using socket communication so here is socket example.
I hope I helped you